# Mysql Query for converting currency and sorting by maxprice

Tags: mysql

I have and SQL query which sorts the properties based on price but when, I add and IF clause with Having it throws an error. Here is my Query

```
SELECT pp_propertylisting.id AS pid,
   pp_propertylisting.title,
   pp_propertylisting.city,
   pp_propertylisting.street,
   pp_propertylisting.country,
   pp_propertylisting.bedrooms,
   pp_propertylisting.bathrooms,
   pp_propertylisting.termsconditions,
   pp_propertyprice.currency,
   pp_propertyimage.imageurl,
   IF(pp_propertyprice.currency='dollar',Max(pp_propertyprice.pricepernight)*0.5,Max(pp_propertyprice.pricepernight)) AS maxiprice,
   pp_propertyimage.title AS imgtitle,
   pp_propertyprice.begindate,



(SELECT max(pp_propertyprice.pricepernight)
 FROM pp_propertyprice
 WHERE pp_propertyprice.propertyid = pp_propertylisting.id) AS maxprice,
   pp_propertyprice.enddate,
   pp_propertylisting.latitude,
   pp_propertylisting.longitude,
   pp_propertylisting.property_maxpeople,
   pp_propertylisting.size,
   pp_propertylisting.buildingsize,
   pp_propertylisting.slug,
   pp_propertylisting.cityslug,
   pp_propertylisting.countryslug,
   pp_propertylisting.continentslug,
   pp_propertylisting.regionslug
   FROM pp_propertyimage,
   pp_propertylisting,
   pp_propertyuntidetails1,
   pp_propertyprice
   WHERE pp_propertyuntidetails1.propertyid = pp_propertylisting.id
   AND pp_propertylisting.id = pp_propertyimage.propertyid
   AND pp_propertyimage.recordlistingid = 1
   AND pp_propertylisting.archivestatus = 0
   AND pp_propertyimage.delstatus = 0
   AND pp_propertyprice.propertyid = pp_propertylisting.id
   AND pp_propertylisting.delstatus=0
   AND pp_propertylisting.approvestatus = 1
   GROUP BY pp_propertylisting.id
   ORDER BY maxprice DESC,
     pp_propertylisting.title DESC HAVING maxiprice > 0
   AND maxiprice < 5000
```

Can you tell me why there is an syntax error.

Comment: Can you please add the errormessage?

Comment: `Max(pp_propertyprice.pricepernight*0.5)` did you mean `Max(pp_propertyprice.pricepernight)*0.5`

Comment: @jens #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY pp_propertylisting.id ORDER BY maxprice DESC, pp_propertylisting.title ' at line 1

Comment: @Abhik Yes I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `having` clause goes after `group by` and before `order by`:

```
SELECT . . .
GROUP BY pp_propertylisting.id
HAVING maxiprice > 0 AND maxiprice < 5000
ORDER BY maxprice DESC, pp_propertylisting.title DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, It worked .. Don't know why i didn't even tried this